# How to deal with indeterminate values in a linear regression?

Tags: regression, logarithm

I have some experimental data over the time. I need to fit this data to two models in their linearized forms:

Model 1: $\ln (a-y)=\ln a-b\ t$

Model 2: $\dfrac{t}{y}=\dfrac{1}{k\ d}+\dfrac{t}{c}$

My data are: (the value of $a$ is the $y$ value at the last time, i.e. $a=4.07$)

```
t       y           ln(a-y)     t/y
-------------------------------------
0       0.00        1.40        Indet
60      3.73        -1.08       16.08
120     3.08        -0.01       38.92
240     4.07        Indet       58.94
```

When I go to plot $\ln (a-y)$ vs. $t$ (model 1) and $\dfrac{t}{y}$ vs. $t$ (model 2), I have to ignore the indeterminate pair of points? or I should replace the indeterminate for 0?. How to deal with the indeterminations in these cases?

Comment: The existence of such a value means your model makes no sense.  In the second case it makes no sense because you have assumed an unrealistic value for the parameter $a,$ which is not a good way to go about estimating it!  In the first case, do you really have data for the point $(t,y)=(0,0),$ or are you just *assuming* this value?

Comment: @whuber Thanks. First, I'd like to know if there is a reference that I can cite for "The existence of such a value means your model makes no sense"?. And the value of the point $(t,y)=(0,0)$ was assumed. $y$ represents the difference between the initial concentration and the concentration at the time, $C_0 - C_i$. As $C_i$ at $t_0$ is $C_0$, I assumed that $(t,y)=(0,0)$

Comment: Your problem, then, is you make assumptions that are inconsistent with your models.  *Don't make them.*  Use the data you have rather than inventing data solely for the purpose of estimating the model parameters.  (You don't need to cite any reference for the fact that division by zero is meaningless: everybody knows this.)